# walk me through tdoa

Tags: geometry, algorithm, spherical-geometry, navigation, trilateration

I'm working on a TDOA application. This is just something in my free time to see if my hardware can accurately do it and it sounded like a cool challenge. Regardless if it looks possible or not, I'm still wanting to try.

So that being said... I wanted to see if someone could help me understand how a location is generated from a 3d set of 4+ receivers when they hear something form an emitter.

In my case, I'm using 4 receivers. I have lat/lng, and alt of all of the receivers. I am logging the times. This is where I start to see variances however in my google research. Some say I need to take a time difference of each receiver. Some say I can calculate the distance. I don't fully understand how it all works. I am find not seeing this with actual numbers, but if anyone could give me a walk through on this. I seek a better understanding of how you get from the timed recordings to a x,y and z positions of the emitter. Everything I find online so far is too vague for me to properly follow along.

And I know what I'm describing isn't trilateration, but seems these two have a lot in common.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format for which requesting personal tuition like this is too broad.